# ODE - existence and uniqueness of a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Let $p(t)$ be a polynomial with no real roots.
I have to prove that the following ODE-IVP:
$$\begin{cases}
y'=\frac{1}{p(xy)}=f(x,y) \\  
y(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$

Has a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$f_y(x,y)=-\frac{p'(xy)x}{(p(xy))^2}$$

I tried to show that $f_y(x,y)$ is bounded at $J\times(\infty,\infty)$ for all closed intervals $J$, but found out that when $p(t)=t^2+t+1$,
$$f_y(x,y)=-\frac{2x^2y+x}{((xy)^2+xy+1)^2},$$

and in that case, $f_y(x,y)$ is not bounded for small values of $y$.

Maybe I should use the Lipschitz condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As $p$ is a polynomial without a real root, $f(x,y)$ is  locally uniformly Lipschitz continuous in $y$ and continuous in $x$. Therefore, the IVP has a unique maximal solution satisfying $y(0)=0$ according to [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem?wprov=sfti1).

Remains to prove that the solution is global on $\mathbb R$. For this, just remind that if a solution has a bounded maximal interval, it explodes in this interval. It’s not the case here as for all $x \in \mathbb R$

$$\vert y(x) \vert \le \frac{\vert x \vert}{k}$$ where $k \gt 0$ is such that $\vert p(t) \vert \gt k$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. The existence of $k$ is a consequence of the fact that $p$ has no real root.